# What does scorched wort taste like?

Tags: wort, off-flavor, burner

I just did my first batch on a campchef propane burner http://cascadeclimbers.com/gear/hiking/product/Camp-Chef-Yukon-Stove.html 
  Problem is that in the during the boil it never crossed my mind that I didn't have to have the burner on high the whole time. Towards the end of the boil when stirring I could feel some gritty harder bits in the bottom of the pot, I assume to be scorched sugars. 
 
 Question is: What type of flavor am I going to be looking for to know if this is what happened, and what other ill effects other than off flavors can I expect this to have caused?

Comment: Was it an extract batch?  If so, did you cut the flame while adding the extract to the kettle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually tastes like ashy burnt sugar.
But if you racked the beer out of the kettle and there wasn't a big black spot in the bottom of the kettle then you have no worries.

Comment: What a relief. No big black burnt spot, just noticed darker small bits of burned sugar rolling around in the bottom. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I don't even know if its possible to have bits of sugar rolling around the bottom of the kettle.  Are you sure it isn't just grain material or hop debris?

Comment: I actually did another batch with the same burner, this time with more control.  Had the same feel in the bottom so it must just have been debris.  I just never noticed on a stove-top batch.